# bot to edit mediawiki categories

Tags: mediawiki, categories, bots

I have a mediawiki with different type of categories.

If a page has 2 categories

```
[[Category:Pear]][[Category:Strawberry]])
```

I want to add a third category

```
[[Category:Fruit_Salad]]
```

Is it possible to do that automatically? (using a bot for instance)

Edit: In fact, what I need is an API for categories

1. a way to read the category
2. a way to add a new category

The rest can be done by any program

Comment: It would require a lot of logic to determine that Pears and Strawberries should yield another categorie of Fruit Salad...

Comment: @Nick Radford what kind of logic? I have already the list of pairs that I want to edit. I guess I just need to access the categories in the database. I am a total newbie in mediawiki, is there a simple way to access them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [pywikipediabot](http://pywikipediabot.sourceforge.net/) framework. (Check catlib.py for the category manipulation code, and category.py for an end-user-friendly mass category modification bot.)